# Active Directory searching what right needs to be added to the app pool identity

Tags: iis-7, active-directory, directoryservices

We have a custom user set for the App Pool Identity for our application.

This user runs the application fine but when it comes to AD authentication the following MS Directory Services API group search returns no groups:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> Principle.GetGroups();
```

However the same code (dll) in our test authentication with the exact same parameters in a windows command line application it returns OK the wanted groups for the found user principle in question.

Somehow the ASP.NET app pool identity appears to have missing 'rights' in that Active Directory when called via the API (which does not error as such and indeed finds the user and authenticates it) returns an empty list of groups after using the above API method  (possibly across multiple domains).

As a workaround we use a TCP/IP port to a command line based server application to reroute the authentication but would dearly like to remove this extra complication as we are sure it is unnecessary, and multiple customers have the issue.

What is the missing part to the user rights that would enable the asp.net application to act the same as the windows login in this respect?

Comment: is the app pool user able to browse and connect to the AD or do login as a normal user on any computer in the AD? you can test browsing the AD with [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/adexplorer.aspx)